# How do I retrieve the variable value aptly in react with callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this code in react app:

```
function xyz (callback) { 
  axios.get(`https://example.com`)
    .then(res => {
      const filepath = res.data.Items[0].filepath.S
      callback ({autoplay: false, controls: true,sources: [{src: filepath}]})
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

function App() {
  return (
    <VideoPlayer { ...xyz(function(response) {console.log(response)});} />
  )
}
```

This works as expected and I can log the response. But what I am trying to do is assign the response of the xyz function directly within the VideoPlayer tags.

For e.g., What I want to achieve is:

`<VideoPlayer {...return-value-of-xyz-function}`

How do I achieve this? Happy to provide more context if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Use some state.

Comment: can you perhaps provide a code snippet to achieve that with states? new to this, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render functions are always synchronous. Because your `xyz` function is asynchronous, you have to deal with all of the intermediary state: loading, error, no data, etc.

I recommend creating a hook for this type of stuff, that way you can establish a pattern and reuse around your app. Or you can take the code from the hook and put it directly in your `App` function - it's up to you.

```
const useFetchData = (url) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isLoading: true, error: null, data: null });
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setState({ isLoading: false, data: res.data, error: null });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setState({ isLoading: false, data: null, error });
      });
  }, [url]);
  return state;
};

const App = () => {
  const { isLoading, data, error } = useFetchData("https://example.com");

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>There was an error: {error}</div>;
  return <VideoPlayer {...data} />;
};
```

Comment: thanks. i think this has got me closer but I am still having issues. Seems like it is not taking the object aptly. when i print data i see `[object Object]` . Printing the string of the object shows me correct object is being passed to <VideoPlayer tag